# meanjs 0.4.0 not working when deployed to Heroku

Tags: heroku, meanjs

I've just tried the meanjs 0.4.0 in local host and runs fine but when I deploy to heroku [link to app](https://meanjsapptest.herokuapp.com/authentication/signup) and try the "Sign up" option I get this in the navegator console:

```
POST https://meanjsapptest.herokuapp.com/api/auth/signup 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

and when I write the comand heroku logs in the CLI I get:

```
2017-06-06T04:15:35.152983+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:16) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153005+00:00 app[web.1]: crypto.js:635
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153006+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new TypeError(
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153006+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153007+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153008+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: The "digest" argument is required and must not be undefined
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153009+00:00 app[web.1]: at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:635:11)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153010+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:628:10)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153012+00:00 app[web.1]: at model. (/app/modules/users/server/models/user.server.model.js:112:26)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153011+00:00 app[web.1]: at model.UserSchema.methods.hashPassword (/app/modules/users/server/models/user.server.model.js:123:19)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153013+00:00 app[web.1]: at _next (/app/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:62:30)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153013+00:00 app[web.1]: at fnWrapper (/app/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:8)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153014+00:00 app[web.1]: at model. (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/plugins/saveSubdocs.js:20:7)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153014+00:00 app[web.1]: at _next (/app/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:62:30)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153015+00:00 app[web.1]: at fnWrapper (/app/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:8)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153015+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/plugins/validateBeforeSave.js:33:13
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153016+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153016+00:00 app[web.1]: at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.153017+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
2017-06-06T04:15:35.167579+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
2017-06-06T04:15:35.173500+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Script restart attempt #1
2017-06-06T04:15:35.292903+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-06T04:15:35.294191+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-06T04:15:35.310954+00:00 app[web.1]: + Error: Certificate file or key file is missing, falling back to non-SSL mode
2017-06-06T04:15:35.311037+00:00 app[web.1]: To create them, simply run the following from your shell: sh ./scripts/generate-ssl-certs.sh
2017-06-06T04:15:35.311039+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-06T04:15:35.916892+00:00 app[web.1]: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
```

I don't know what to do now because Heroku supports tell me thar the error is in my code but I haven't changed anything there!

[CLI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW4Jc.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just had this problem. We were able to fix it by enforcing our preferred node version in package.json > engines.

We previously had it at

```
"node": ">=0.10.0"
```

We changed it to

```
"node": "6.6.0"
```

And then pushed that to Heroku, and that fixed the issue.

Not entirely sure what the problem is, but we found this link which lead us to believe the node version was the issue:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v4-LTS-and-v6-LTS#crypto

Comment: You were right. I changed the node version in "package.json" and now it works fine.